# Swagger creating an extra definition for students when already in the students entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Right im still just as confused in ef core 5.10 I am creating a model as suggested by the new method.

I have the model as.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Students>().HasMany(x => x.Workouts)
  .WithMany(x => x.Students)
  .UsingEntity<StudentWorkout>(
   x => x.HasOne(x => x.WorkOuts)
  .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId),
  x => x.HasOne(x => x.Students)
  .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkOutId));
```

This is the code I use to attach combines to students.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Students>().HasMany(x => x.Combines)
.WithMany(x => x.Students)
.UsingEntity<StudentCombines>(
x => x.HasOne(x => x.Combines)
.WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId),
x => x.HasOne(x => x.Students)
.WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CombinesId));
```

It created its table here fine

[image]

What I dont get is why on earth is my swagger defination creating an extra entry for students in workouts json

```
"workouts": [
  {
    "workOutId": 0,
    "studentId": 0,
    "tb": 0,
    "op": 0,
    "pu": 0,
    "bp": 0,
    "bj": 0,
    "notes": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "string",
        "shortNotes": "string",
        "longNotes": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "notesAccessLevel": true,
        "tennantId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "isDeleted": true,
        "isActive": true,
        "createdBy": "string",
        "lastModifiedBy": "string",
        "lastUpdatedDate": "2021-09-22T22:35:08.380Z",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-22T22:35:08.380Z"
      }
    ],
    "students": [
      "string"
    ],
    "isBlackLevel": true,
    "canEdit": true,
    "ispb": true,
    "isDeleted": true,
    "isActive": true,
    "createdBy": "string",
    "lastModifiedBy": "string",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2021-09-22T22:35:08.381Z",
    "createdDate": "2021-09-22T22:35:08.381Z"
  }
],
```

My Workout class

```
public class Workouts
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkOutId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; } 
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public decimal? BJ { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; } = new List<Students>();
   public bool? IsBlackLevel { get; set; }
   public bool? CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool? ISPB { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }  
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Student Class I also have two others another class called Combines bscailly

```
public class Students
{   [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public string? Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Combines> Combines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Workouts> Workouts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }   
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Quesiton is do i need to add json ignore to stop this being output via swagger?.
Under the workout json as you see. Am already in the students json so why would I need to get them again.

"students": [
"string"
],

In my Api Controlers

The two functions that use students look like this.

```
public List<Students> GetAllStudents()
{
   return db.Students.Where(w => w.IsActive == true && w.IsDeleted == false).Include(i => i.Notes).Include(i => i.Classes).Include(i => i.Workouts).Include(I=>I.Combines).ToList();
}

public Students GetStudentById(int StudentId)
{
 return db.Students.Where(w =>w.StudentId== StudentId && w.IsActive == true && w.IsDeleted == false).Include(i => i.Notes).Include(i=>i.Classes).Include(i => i.Workouts).Include(I => I.Combines).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I simply want One Student to Many , Workouts , Classes and Combines

My json is screwed up as well returning students. in amongst the workout when it should just be the workouts :-(.

As Far as I can tell by the docs you still need this in EF5.10

```
public class StudentWorkout
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }       
    public int WorkOutId { get; set; }
    //You can add extra properties here
    //relationships
    public Students Students { get; set; }
    public Workouts WorkOuts { get;  set; }
}
```

In that table I have the following

[image]

Which should give me 1 student with 2 work outs in the jason response but its not.

As per this data.

[image]

**Edit 2**
Ok I found my issue with the data mapping

I found my answer I had the id's the wrong way round in the on creating segment so it was obv using the workout ids for the person instead of the actual column was meant to use.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Students>().HasMany(x => x.Workouts)
.WithMany(x => x.Students)
.UsingEntity<StudentWorkout>(
 x => x.HasOne(x => x.WorkOuts)
 .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkOutId),
 x => x.HasOne(x => x.Students)
 .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId));


 modelBuilder.Entity<Students>().HasMany(x => x.Combines)
 .WithMany(x => x.Students)
 .UsingEntity<StudentCombines>(
  x => x.HasOne(x => x.Combines)
 .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CombinesId),
 x => x.HasOne(x => x.Students)
 .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId));
```

I had them wrong way round here but still does not explain the extra students in the workout bit.

Comment: Yes, if you have navigation properties to make it easier to query but you don't want those navigation properties to be included in the json output, you have to annotate them with `JsonIgnore` or similar

Comment: I also found my other problem about why 1 and 2 was getting the wrong ids for workuts I had them the wrong way round lol @AndrewWilliamson

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson bit of a strange way ef core 5 handles the one to many to be honest lol

Comment: Navigation properties are a lot easier if you follow the suggested naming conventions, e.g. if your 'Student' class (singular, no trailing 's') had a primary key called 'Id', 'Workout' had a primary key 'Id' and a foreign key 'StudentId', then the navigation properties would work without you needing to do all the configuration yourself

Comment: I do for most things but the people using the data need clear field names which can sometimes ditact what you name them, I always use Id but you still have ot have the navigation properties with ef 5

Comment: Forget last I had to use Netown Json net not internal .net System

Comment: You can always annotate or use `modelBuilder` to explicitly specify the column name that a property maps to. Using a well established convention, like the one defined by Entity Framework, will make it easier to read if you leave the project for a year and come back to it, or if new developers pick it up, and it would have helped you spot the configuration error much quicker

Comment: Can you update this question for clarity, i.e. remove or reorganise things that have been resolved in the comments and narrow down the question to just the unanswered content. Also, I would recommend you strip some of the properties out of your classes if they aren't relevant to the question, it will make the question easier to read and more likely to get an answer

Comment: Its already been answered by u and fixed

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thanks for your tip i reset my class names and as you said ef core handles it istself I just should stuck to standards would made this easier ;-)

Comment: Do not allow business "people" to dictate what you do with what they need not know about. You can always do what you need and satisfy them too. Allowing a name to force you to go against conventions which creates more code that needs to be maintained every time they want to see a different name isn't a good thing - at all.